# How to populate latitude and longitude after filling the input field using Google Map in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am using Google Map API to get autocomplete data into input field using JavaScript. I am providing my code below.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="pick_addr" name="pick_addr" required="required" tabindex="2" placeholder="Enter pick up address" ng-model="pick_addr" autocomplete="off">
<input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="src_lat" name="src_lat" required="required" tabindex="2" ng-model="src_lat">
<input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="src_lon" name="src_lon" required="required" tabindex="2" ng-model="src_lon">

<script>
function initMap() {
   var input = document.getElementById('pick_addr');
   var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
}
</script>
```

Here I can get the autocomplete data successfully using Google Map API but I need when that field has autocomplete data the respective latitude and longitude will be fetched to both hidden field.

Comment: well, have you checked the docs? you could use the address for example in the geocoder and get the lat lng values: 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/geocoder

Comment: See how [this example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete) is setting the map center.

Answer (score 0):

To get the latitude and longitude of the place result put this code in the `place_changed` callback function (fires when the user selects a place)

```
document.getElementById("src_lat").value = place.geometry.location.lat();
document.getElementById("src_lon").value = place.geometry.location.lng();
```

[image: result (without hidden text inputs)]

```js
function initMap() {
  var input = document.getElementById('pick_addr');
  var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);


  // Set the data fields to return when the user selects a place.
  autocomplete.setFields(
    ['address_components', 'geometry', 'icon', 'name']);
  autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {

    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
    if (!place.geometry) {
      // User entered the name of a Place that was not suggested and
      // pressed the Enter key, or the Place Details request failed.
      window.alert("No details available for input: '" + place.name + "'");
      return;
    }

    document.getElementById("src_lat").value = place.geometry.location.lat();
    document.getElementById("src_lon").value = place.geometry.location.lng();
  });
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="pick_addr" name="pick_addr" required="required" tabindex="2" placeholder="Enter pick up address" ng-model="pick_addr" autocomplete="off">
<input class="form-control" id="src_lat" name="src_lat" required="required" tabindex="2" ng-model="src_lat">
<input class="form-control" id="src_lon" name="src_lon" required="required" tabindex="2" ng-model="src_lon">

<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&libraries=places&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
```